# Dependency Injection not working, but defined manually

Tags: php, symfony, service, dependency-injection

I'm new to Symfony and try to use the ClientManipulatorInterface service from gos/web-socket-bundle. 
My problem is that Symfony returns an error even if I configure the argument manually.

I always get this error: Cannot autowire service "Foo\Bar\Controller\testTopic": argument "$clientManipulator" of method "__construct()" references interface "Gos\Bundle\WebSocketBundle\Client\ClientManipulatorInterface" but no such service exists. You should maybe
  alias this interface to the existing "gos_web_socket.websocket.client_manipulator" service.

Here is my service.yaml:

```
services:
    test_topic:
        class: Foo\Bar\Controller\testTopic
        tags:
            - { name: gos_web_socket.topic }
        arguments:
            - '@gos_web_socket.websocket.client_manipulator'
```

This is my PHP class:

```
namespace Foo\Bar\Controller;

use Gos\Bundle\WebSocketBundle\Client\ClientManipulatorInterface;
use Gos\Bundle\WebSocketBundle\Topic\TopicInterface;

class testTopic implements TopicInterface {

    /**
     * @var ClientManipulatorInterface
     */
    protected $clientManipulator;

    /**
     * testTopic constructor.
     * @param ClientManipulatorInterface $clientManipulator
     */
    public function __construct(ClientManipulatorInterface $clientManipulator) {
        $this->clientManipulator = $clientManipulator;
    }

    ...
```

Comment: I know you already accepted the answer but the actual problem with your config is that you used a service id of test_topic instead of Foo\Bar\Controller\testTopic.  The error message is actually coming from autowire as it scans all of your classes and attempts to automatically convert them to services.  Autowire uses the class name so see if a service is manually defined.  In your case, it does not find your service so it tries to create it and runs into the interface problem.  In other words, change the service id to the class name and your original config would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to alias the `ClientManipulatorInterface` to one of it's implementations for Symfony to be able to autowire the dependency correctly:

```
services:
    Gos\Bundle\WebSocketBundle\Client\ClientManipulatorInterface: '@gos_web_socket.websocket.client_manipulator'

    Foo\Bar\Controller\testTopic:
        autowire: true
        tags:
            - { name: gos_web_socket.topic }
```

Clear your cache afterwards!

Comment: I expected that it is automatically done because it is defined in the gos/web-socket-bundle. Now I defined it also in my services.yaml and it work's. Thanks.

Comment: The bundle's [service-definitions](https://github.com/GeniusesOfSymfony/WebSocketBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/services/services.yml) don't include the interface alias - that's why auto-wiring doesn't work out of the box.